# Finding variable name from instruction pointer using debugging symbols

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, static, symbols

I'm looking for a way to find the names of the variables accessed by a given instruction (that performs a memory access).

Using debugging symbols and, for example, addr2line or objdump it's easy to convert instruction addresses into source code files + line numbers, but unfortunately often a single source code line contains more than one variable so this method does not have sufficiently fine granularity.

I've found that objdump is able to convert instruction addresses to global variables. But I haven't yet found a way to do this for local variables. For example, in the example bellow, I'd like to know that instruction at address 0x4004c4 is accessing the local variable "local_hello" and that the instruction at address 0x4004c9 is accessing the local variable "local_hello2".

Hello.c:

```
int global_hello = 4;

int main(){
    int local_hello = 3;
    int local_hello2 = 0;
    local_hello2 = global_hello + local_hello;
    return local_hello2;
}
```

Using "objdump -S hello":

```
local_hello2 = global_hello + local_hello;
4004be:  8b 15 cc 03 20 00   mov    0x2003cc(%rip),%edx    # 600890 <global_hello>
4004c4:  8b 45 fc            mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
4004c7:  01 d0               add    %edx,%eax
4004c9:  89 45 f8            mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for simple programs with no or only moderate optimization levels but will become difficult with compiler optimzation.

You might want to look into gdb sources to learn about the efforts to connect variables to optimized compiler output.

What's your objective, after all?

Comment: It would be good enough to find a solution that works for non-optimized code. I was hopping that this information is stored in the usual compiler debugging symbols. I'm interested in getting this type of information in the context of a project to detect and analyze data races.

Comment: @Warydo, perhaps it is easier to work with the source (take something like [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse)) or istrument the compiler (e.g. using [LLWM](http://llvm.org) as starting point).